# /*csv*/ in select queries

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I use `/*csv*/` in my select statement, would it use all the available cores on the server side? Or just 1?

I am planning to do something like this:

```
spool "\path\to\spool1.txt"

select /*csv*/ * from employees;
```

I cannot use all the cores. I used `/*+ parallel(auto) */` and I got reprimanded. I cannot use anymore than 1 core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the CSV bit, is a SQL Developer and SQLcl specific output formatting thing, where client-side we take the output and auto-format it to CSV. That's ZERO DB processes there.

The database generally automatically will parallelism your queries as needed.

> When the parameter PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY is set to AUTO, Oracle
>   Database automatically decides if a statement should execute in
>   parallel or not and what DOP it should use

[DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#CIHGJFFH)

You can additionally define your TABLEs in advance to be setup for parallel degree queries.

```
CREATE TABLE PARALLEL_5
(
  COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(20) 
, COLUMN2 INT 
) 
PARALLEL 5;
```

So don't use the Parallel hint to stay out of trouble with your DBA.

However, your DBA could also just take care of it by using a resource consumer group policy to restrict you automatically.

> Degree of Parallelism Limit You can limit the maximum degree of
>   parallelism for any operation within a consumer group. The degree of
>   parallelism is the number of parallel execution servers that are
>   associated with a single operation. Use the PARALLEL_DEGREE_LIMIT_P1
>   directive attribute to specify the degree of parallelism for a
>   consumer group.

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm#ADMIN11854)